# Project Floodlight - Listening for openflow messages

Tags: sdn, openflow, google-floodlight

I am using project Floodlight to understand the software defined networking for my personal project. My custom module uses floodlightProvider controller module and IOFMessageListener to listen for openflow messages. I can successfully listen to PACKET_IN openflow messages, however I am not able to listen to any synchronous openflow messages(HELLO, EQHO_REQUEST, etc). I followed the documentation and if I am not mistaken, openflow messages can be listened by using the floodlightProvider controller module. Can anyone assist me as I am very curious. The program for listening for messages is given on floodlight tutorial under "how to write a module" . However, I am editing the startup method and the receive method. Those are as follows:

```
@Override
public void startUp(FloodlightModuleContext context) {
    floodlightProvider.addOFMessageListener(OFType.PACKET_IN, this);
    floodlightProvider.addOFMessageListener(OFType.HELLO, this);
}

@Override
   public net.floodlightcontroller.core.IListener.Command receive(IOFSwitch sw, OFMessage msg, FloodlightContext cntx) {
        switch(msg.getType()){
            case PACKET_IN:
             // print the openflow message in console
                break;
            case HELLO:
            // print the openflow message in console
               break;
            default:
               break;
}
        return Command.CONTINUE;
    }
```